# expo-secure-store not working in bare React Native App

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have an app, that is made in bare react native. I am trying to use expo's expo-secure-store. But, it's not working. It is giving me the following error:
`[Error: The method or property SecureStore.setItemAsync is not available on ios, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?]`
It was working in 1 of my expo apps.
I have react-native-unimodules installed, but, not expo.
Do I require to install expo too? I think that would defeat the whole purpose.
Are there any other alternatives that I can use? Or someone can tell me how to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I ended up using an alternative: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sensitive-info

Comment: I found a solution, in my case, I was missing a line in MainApplication.java. I should have read more carefully the installation process. Seems to work now.

Comment: react-native-sensitive-info is not secure in android. You can use react-native-encrypted-storage or expo-secure-store.